# where is defined kmap_atomic

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a kernel module that works good in x86 system. but when i want to compile it on raspbian buster os and ARMv8-a cpu, it gives below error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘kmap_atomic’; did you mean ‘in_atomic’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
#define __pte_map(pmd)  (pte_t *)kmap_atomic(pmd_page(*(pmd)))
```

module that i want to compile is https://github.com/misc0110/PTEditor. now there is anyone could help me to resolve above error.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this would be resolved by including `linux/highmem.h`.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by adding that include.

Comment: Search in indexed kernel source at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/highmem.h#L91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is apparently missing an include of `linux/highmem.h`.